# Vue Chart, Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have a chart using vue-chart. In the mydata array I need to enter data which are coming from store.js file. I need to push those data to the mydata but without using any button.

```
    counter1:0,
    counter2:0,
    counter3:0
```

and this  is the Chart data

```
      data(){
      return {
        mylabel : 'TestDataLabel',
        mylabels : ['1', '2', '3','4','5','6'],
        mydata : [100, 40, 60]
      }
  },
```

I need to push this counter values to mydata array of vue-chart , and this values are updating in another component. I have this updated values in the chart component using computed prop. How can I push these data to the mydata array without using any button.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `store.js` a vuex store?
If so, you can simply use a getter / computed prop and then set it to `mydata`